# Using LWC and an Imperative APEX method, I cannot reference the parameter being passed into APEX because it is a promise

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, promises

I have an apex method which receives a country name and returns a country code.

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable = true)
public static String getCountryCode(String searchString) {
    //TODO add the code to lookup the country code
    String result = 'test';
    System.debug('ALH searchString='+searchString);
    System.debug('ALH result='+result);
    return result;
}
```

I will add the logic later to do the lookup, for now I am just trying to get the searchString into the apex method.

Here is part of my js code

```
import getCC from '@salesforce/apex/NewAccountController.getCountryCode';


@track searchCountry;
@track searchCountryCode;
@track foundCountryCode;

grabCC() {      
const searchccId=this.searchCountry;
                if (searchccId) {
                getCC ( {searchccId} ) 
                    .then(result => {
                        this.searchCountryCode = result;
                        this.foundCountryCode=true;
                        }    
                    })
                    .catch (error => {
                        console.log('catch error ' + error.message);
                    });
}}
```

When I look at my debug log in for the APEX code it shows:
ALH searchString=null
ALH result=test

I understand that the input string is a "promise", but how can i force it to be passed in so that I can use the searchString in my APEX code?

Comment: This problem was similar but different cause.  Thank you so much for the reply, this one had me stumpped. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring parameter of name ***searchString*** in apex method but you are passing ***searchccId***. Below are the 3 options to fix:

**Option 1:**

```
const searchString =this.searchCountry;
     if (searchString) {
         getCC ( { searchString  } ) 
             .then(result => {
```

**Option 2:**

```
const searchccId =this.searchCountry;
     if (searchccId) {
         getCC ( { searchString: searchccId } ) 
             .then(result => {
```

**Option 3:**

```
 if (this.searchCountry) {
     getCC ( { searchString: this.searchCountry } ) 
         .then(result => {
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can't believe I missed that.  Works great now.  THANK YOU!